# Object undefined values

Tags: asp.net, typescript, react-typescript

Why is my tmp object getting undefined values?

The fetch is getting the object right, maybe `<FormStructure {...this.state.system} />` is the wrong syntax to give the Element the object?

```
export default class System extends React.Component<any, State> {
    constructor(props: any) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            system: new SystemClass(),
        }
        this.GetData();
    }

    public render() {
        return (
                <div>
                    <FormStructure {...this.state.system} />
                </div>
            );
    }

    private GetData = (): void => {
        fetch('api/Admin/Get', {
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            method: 'GET'
        })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => this.setState({ system: Helper.ConvertData(data, SystemClass) as SystemClass }))
            .then(() => console.log(this.state.system))
    };
}


const FormStructure = (system: SystemClass) => {

   const onFill = () => {
      var tmp = { name: system.name, street: system.street };
      console.log(tmp);
      console.log(system);
   }
}
```

[image: Console.log(tmp / system) in onFill]

[image: Console.log(system) in Get]

Comment: But back to your question: the syntax `{...this.state.system}` should be fine as long `this.state.system` is an object.

Comment: But it is not a object but a class you are spreading. I would have to check it but I think this won't work. A class in javascript is like a function. This you cannot spread like an object. I hope we talk about the same when I say object: `{"key": "value"} : { [key: string]: string; }`

Comment: I see, classes works when using the spread operator but only properties and not functions inside class. :)